# SimpleXML Error in Parsing XML documents that have multiple lines written declaring the version & encoding

Tags: php, mysql, xml, api, simplexml

The document to parse in PHPs simpleXML has multiple entries of:
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
throughout the file. The file is essentially a collection of 10-15 of the same iteration of tags with different values inside. 
One solution I found to resolving the repeat of this tag was to go through and manually delete `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`in all of the other occurrences, but I prefer to have it done automatically because this will be a reoccurring issue.

How can I remove the lines of code or ignore the lines of code with the re-declaration of `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`?

I've tried deleting each instance of  manually and using the replacestring() function. 
1. The manual removal is very time demanding.
2. replacestr() throws an error because there are many " " within the XML file that stop translation.

I expect to filter through this XML file and store the values of each/some of the tags in mysql using the mysqli connection.  Some of the values within tags I would also like to translate "true" and "false" values to a boolean integer before inserting the data into a matching mysql row.

Comment: It is invalid XML, so you will have to repair the document before loading using string functions and/or regular expressions. Take care that the document has a single document element as well.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have a series of XML documents in the one file and so trying to just remove the xml header will leave you with an invalid XML document (as it will have several root elements - one for each document).

You could split the content by the header (using `explode()`) - and the process each one as an individual XML document...

```
$data = file_get_contents($fileName);
$docs = explode('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', $data);
// Remove first document as it will be empty
array_shift($docs);
foreach ( $docs as $doc )   {
    $xml = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'.$doc);
    // Process XML file
    echo $xml->getName().PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work when i entered this code into a php document and changed the $filename to my files directory. It didn't throw an error so i guess after echo$xml->getName().PHP_EOL; theres supposed to be the simplexml identifiers i'm searching in the file

Comment: I'ts impossible to tell without a file your trying to process what is going on.  You could try and output `$doc` inside the loop and see what that displays.